# about infinite repetition of star quantifier

Tags: regex

I have a question.

Looking at the image below, no highlight about the match result.

[image]

But when i use the global modifier, highlight is displayed.

I don't understand what is the difference.

[image]

And when i use non-word character without global modifier, highlight is displayed. What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: There _is_ a highlight in the first image. It's the dotted line in front of the very first character, because `\w*` matched _zero_ characters, so it's displayed as a line.

Comment: If global modifier is off then engine stops at the very first match.

Comment: I thought operate of `\w`  is first step and operate of `*` is second step. So `\w*` matched `0123456789`. Am i wrong?:)

Comment: You are partially wrong - `\w*` matches **zero** or more times, so it is always true.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Have a nice day~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that a string like `abc` is seen by a regex engine as `EMPTY STRING` + `a` + `EMPTY STRING` + `b` + `EMPTY STRING` + `c` + `EMPTY STRING`.

> no highlight about the match result

`\w*` matches 0 or more word chars. So, it can match an EMPTY STRING. The regex engine processes the string from left to right. So, the first EMPTY STRING is located at the beginning of the string - and it is highlighed on the first screenshot.

> But when i use the global modifier, highlight is displayed.

Because the global modifier tests all the locations in the string, and then it can match whole *chunks* of *consecutive* word chars.

> And when i use non-word character without global modifier, highlight is displayed.

Because without a global modifier, the `\W*` matches the non-word chars at the beginning of the string, zero or more occurrences.

Comment: A `*` is a quantifier, it just changes how many chars/sequences of chars the quantified atom can match. `\w*9` matches 0 or more word chars followed by `9`.

Comment: Sorry. I deleted my comment accidentally. I wonder why `\w*` don't move to second line after scaned first line.:)

Comment: As I mentioned, string processed from left to right, regex engine does not just jumps anywhere if it does not have to.

Comment: For example, if insert `a`, string `a` in the fourth line is highlighted after first, second and third line was scanned. But If insert `a*`, regex engine stayed on the first line. I do not know why there is a difference.

Comment: `a` regex makes it obligatory to match a single `a` (1 time if no global modifier is set), and `a*` can match an empty space, 1 `a`, 2 `a`s, and more (usually, MAX_UINT times, that depends on the regex library/implmentation).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.:) But regex is very difficult. I have to study more. I have a last question. `a*` can match`empty string`, `a`, `aa`, `aaa`, more. And `*` is greedy quantifiers. Why `*` highlighted not `a` but `empty string`?

Comment: Because the regex engine processes a string from left to right. The `*` quantifier is greedy and matches as many chars it quantifies as it can. At the start of the string you have an EMPTY STRING and then a non-`a`. So, the longest string it can match is EMPTY STRING. It is expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment. I truly appreciate. Have a nice day~